# jquery validator addMethod not working

Tags: jquery

After much effort I've been completely unable to get the addMethod to work.

The code i have is as follows:

```
$("#submitform").validate(
        {
            rules: {
                org_name: "required",
                email_address: "required",
                phone: "required",
                abn: "required",
                description: "required",
                geocomplete: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                org_name: "Required",
                email_address: "Required",
                phone: "Required",
                abn: "Required",
                description: "Required",
                geocomplete: "Required"
            },              
            submitHandler: function(event, validator) {     


                // submitForm();

            },
            invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                //code..
            }
    });
```

the addMethod

```
    $.validator.addMethod("org_name", function(value) {
     // return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1];
     console.log("hi" + value);alert('hi');
     return false;
    }, "Invalid");
```

and the target element

```
<input id="org_name" name="org_name" type="text" class="input-xlarge ">
```

The addMethod function is not being called, there are no errors and i'm at a loss with this one??
On the other hand the "Required" validation is working fine on the form as expected, this is my first foray into this plugin.

Comment: Please see this http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the rule like,

```
 org_name: "org_name",
```

Your code should be like,

```
 $("#submitform").validate(
    {
        rules: {
            org_name: "org_name",// input element: method name
            email_address: "required",
            phone: "required",
            abn: "required",
            description: "required",
            geocomplete: "required"
        },
```